# How to print whole array in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I want to print the whole array in tcsh, because then i want to pipe it to uniq, is there a way to do it in tcsh.

i had `set array`

and was printing it:

```
echo "$array"
```

but it ended up with error: Word too long, it works for smaller arrrays,

Is there some simple way to do it?

Comment: Also posted on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19847234/827263).

Comment: @Ricsie  please show your whole script or steps you are performing. This could help to troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a very old version of tcsh, that *Word too long* limit was removed in tcsh version 6.14.03 in 2006.

```
echo "$array"
```

Would pass the concatenation of the array elements to `echo` as one element but fail if any contain a newline character.

```
echo "$array:q"
```

would be more correct to pass the concatenation of all elements.

To pass all the elements of the array (except the empty ones; though that will be [fixed in the next release](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/commit/51f7c9361de62d7106eafc6cb0c33cc6701de9e2)) as separate arguments to `echo`, that would be:

```
echo $array:q
```

But if `echo "$array"` fails for you with *Word too long*, `echo` in that very old version may also fail with *echo: Too many arguments.*.

Answer (score 0):

In tcsh you'd use arrays as follow.

Define the array

```
set myarray = ( element1 element2 element3 element4 etc )
```

Output the whole array

```
printf '%s\n' "$array[-]"
```

Print element 1 to 3

```
printf '%s\n' "$array[1-3]"
```

NOTE:  In Bash the first element of the array starts at `0` (zero).

Also add `set verbose` on top of your script to see what lines are interpreted and where it fails.

Comment: How would that address the `Word too long` error?

Comment: @KeithThompson making sure he understands how arrays work in *csh shells.

Comment: Ok, but `echo "$array"` should work perfectly well to print an entire array -- except for the "Word too long" problem, to which `printf '%s\n' "$array[-]"` is equally vulnerable.

Comment: @KeithThompson  except he shows `set array` only which will result to nothing (empty) output. He probably is overriding the array somehow and resulting in the error.  `set array; echo $array` should return nothing, let alone "Word too long"

Comment: Hmm. I assumed that `set array` was an abbreviation of the actual command he used. If he got "word too long", he's obviously setting it to *something*. Your recent comment on the question is a good one.

Comment: Yes im setting it to  quiet a long list of lines, where are few whic hare two or more times and need to sort it and do a uniq